# CEPH for video streaming?

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, ceph, glusterfs-3.5

So i have a video streaming app (**HLS**) and was wondering if using CEPH or GlusterFS would be a good idea vs using plain SAN storage?
(from performance prospective)

In general is software defined the silver bullet for storage (can it be used anywhere?)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is a silver bullet.

Build versus buy a shared storage array is a matter of operational preference more than anything. Either can be sized to most requirements, and either can provide block, file or object storage.

Build your own multi node solution such as with Ceph or Gluster gives you control of the storage software and hardware. It may have a cost advantage if you buy commodity hardware and save software expense. Scaling to very large sizes is possible, if you can deploy enough nodes. Purchasing support is still required if you don't have the expertise in multi node clusters to repair it when it breaks.

Commercial off the shelf centralized storage storage arrays are also an option. Terabyte to petabyte class capacities serving thousands to millions of IOPS are available, providing performance sufficient to most workloads. Delivery as an appliance allows you outsource the array architecture and just let it deliver lots of LUNs and file shares. Enterprise support levels are expected, but you pay for the privilege.